# installation passenger module for nginx failed

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nginx, debian, passenger

I want to add Passenger support do my debian9/nginx server.

I've installed ruby and rails via apt.

`apt-get install -y libnginx-mod-http-passenger` leads to this error msg:

```
 *The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     libnginx-mod-http-passenger : Depends: nginx-common (= 1.10.3-1+deb9u1) but 1.12.2-1~dotdeb+8.1 is to be installed
    E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.*

my config: 
    uname -r ==> 4.9.0-4-amd64
    cat /etc/debian_version ==> 9.3

nginx -V ==> 
    nginx version: nginx/1.12.2
    built with OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016
    TLS SNI support enabled
    configure arguments: --with-cc-opt='-g -O2 -fstack-protector-strong        -Wformat -Werror=format-security -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2' --with-ld-opt='-Wl,-z,relro -Wl,-z,now' --prefix=/usr/share/nginx --conf-path=/etc/nginx/nginx.conf --http-log-path=/var/log/nginx/access.log --error-log-path=/var/log/nginx/error.log --lock-path=/var/lock/nginx.lock --pid-path=/run/nginx.pid --modules-path=/usr/lib/nginx/modules --http-client-body-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/body --http-fastcgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/fastcgi --http-proxy-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/proxy --http-scgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/scgi --http-uwsgi-temp-path=/var/lib/nginx/uwsgi --with-debug --with-pcre-jit --with-http_ssl_module --with-http_stub_status_module --with-http_realip_module --with-http_auth_request_module --with-http_v2_module --with-http_dav_module --with-file-aio --with-threads --with-http_addition_module --with-http_geoip_module=dynamic --with-http_gunzip_module --with-http_gzip_static_module --with-http_image_filter_module=dynamic --with-http_secure_link_module --with-http_sub_module --with-http_xslt_module=dynamic --with-stream=dynamic --with-stream_realip_module --with-stream_geoip_module --with-stream_ssl_module --with-stream_ssl_preread_module --with-mail=dynamic --with-mail_ssl_module --add-dynamic-module=/usr/src/builddir/debian/modules/nginx-auth-pam --add-module=/usr/src/builddir/debian/modules/nginx-dav-ext-module --add-module=/usr/src/builddir/debian/modules/nginx-echo --add-module=/usr/src/builddir/debian/modules/nginx-upstream-fair --add-module=/usr/src/builddir/debian/modules/ngx_http_substitutions_filter_module --add-module=/usr/src/builddir/debian/modules/nginx-cache-purge


ruby -v ==> ruby 2.3.3p222 (2016-11-21) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
rails -v ==> Rails 4.2.7.1
```

So far I have followed the official tutorial, [here](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/install/nginx/install/oss/stretch/).

Answer (score 1):

Old question but answer may interest someone ;)

As far as I understand `libnginx-mod-http-passenger`, it forces the version of `nginx` to use (here  **= 1.10.3-1+deb9u1**), but you have the **1.12.2** installed (either compiled or using *backports*).

You then need to donwgrade nginx (using *stable* rep for exemple) in order to be able to use the precompiled module. Else you can [put passenger behind a nginx reverse proxy](https://www.phusionpassenger.com/library/deploy/standalone/reverse_proxy.html).

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to run this command

> apt-get install -y libnginx-mod-http-passenger

with sudo ?

Also try to run

> sudo apt-get autoclean

which will remove packages that can't be downloaded

and afterwards the below command which will use the -f flag

> sudo apt-get install -fy libnginx-mod-http-passenger

Comment: sure, i did run all the commands as su.
also with your last suggestion with the -fy option, I get the same error msg..